# Replace constructor in class component with Functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Thanks in Advance.

Am trying to implement React Native push notification on my project.
So how do i replace this code in class component with functional component.
I use React Hooks and functional components

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.notif = new NotifService(
      this.onRegister.bind(this),
      this.onNotif.bind(this),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would transform this into a functional component by setting up an empty object state with a `useState` hook and wrapping the `notif` value in a `useMemo` hook with an empty dependency list. I'm not experienced with React Native components so I created empty callbacks with the `useCallback` hook to supplement the missing class methods you're referencing. If those are related to React Native API, I am assuming there are equivalent hook exports you can reference.

```
 import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
 
 const App = props => {
   const [state, setState] = useState({})
   const onRegister = useCallback(() => {}, [])
   const onNotif = useCallback(() => {}, [])
   
   const notif = useMemo(() => {
     return new NotifService(onRegister, onNotif)
   }, [])

   return (<>render notif.message (if exists): {notif.message}</>)
 }
```